# BAT File to delete old log entries from a TXT File

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, logging

I have a PC which runs specific BAT files at different times in the day. In order to ensure I keep track that all tasks are occurring I make each task register an entry in a log file called `tack.txt`. This is typically how it looks:

> ```
> Start Cams @ 10/09/2016 15:11:43 
> Update List @ 11/09/2016 14:13:47
> EPG Update @ 11/09/2016 16:59:48 
> Start Cams @ 11/09/2016 17:01:35 
> Restart @ 13/09/2016 17:16:52
> ```

Each entry is on a separate line and has a date and time as presented.

Is it possible to have create a BAT file which deletes entries older than say 3 days to keep the process tidy?

Comment: A simple exe would do it. How about a process runs every night and uses three files for the previous days, copying them to the previous day(s). To view it you would concatenate them and display as you wish.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you need to show your own efforts! We are not going to write a script for you for free! Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's hard to get yesterday's date with Batch (handling special cases across months/years/leapdays), but it's easy with a bit of help from Powershell.

You can get the dates like this:

```
for /f %%a in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-2).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')"') do ( set today-2=%%a )
```

Then you can search for them like this, and output the matching lines to a file:

```
findstr "%today-2% %today-1% %today%" test.txt >matching.txt
```

Then you can replace your log file with matching.txt via `copy /y` and `del`.